# How to use toString and getter and setter methods

Tags: java, string, overriding

I'm riding the struggle bus with the below instructions. I can't figure out how to use the toString() method to print my data values. I also don't know how to get the color to print as a string to say "Black" or "Blue". And I can't figure out how to use the boolean value to say "connected" or "disconnected".

> Create a Java class named HeadPhone to represent a headphone set. The class contains:
>
> • Three constants named LOW, MEDIUM and HIGH with values of 1, 2 and 3
>   to denote the headphone volume.
>
> • A private int data field named volume that specifies the volume of
>   the headphone. The default volume is MEDIUM.
>
> • A private boolean data field named pluggedIn that specifies if the
>   headphone is plugged in. The default value if false.
>
> • A private String data field named manufacturer that specifies the
>   name of the manufacturer of the headphones.
>
> • A private Color data field named headPhoneColor that specifies the
>   color of the headphones.
>
> • getter and setter methods for all data fields.
>
> • A no argument constructor that creates a default headphone.
>
> • A method named toString() that returns a string describing the
>   current field values of the headphones.
>
> • A method named changeVolume(value) that changes the volume of the
>   headphone to the value passed into the method
>
> Create a TestHeadPhone class that constructs at least 3 HeadPhone
>   objects.

```
public class TestHeadPhone {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // construct an object
        HeadPhone headPhone = new HeadPhone();

        System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + headPhone.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("Color: " + headPhone.getColor());
        System.out.println("Currently: " + headPhone.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Volume: " + headPhone.getVolume());
        if(headPhone.getStatus() == false){
            System.out.println("Please plug the Head Phones into a device.");   
        }

        headPhone.setNewHeadphone();

        System.out.println("\n" + "Manufacturer: " + 
            headPhone.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("Color: " + headPhone.getColor());
        System.out.println("Currently: " + headPhone.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Volume: " + headPhone.getVolume());
        if(headPhone.getStatus() == true){
            System.out.println("Currently playing classical music.");   
        }

    }

}

package testheadphone;
// import color class
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class HeadPhone {
    // class variables
    private static final int LOW = 1;
    private static final int MEDIUM = 2;
    private static final int HIGH = 3;
    private int volume = MEDIUM;
    private boolean pluggedIn = false;
    private String manufacturer;
    private Color headPhoneColor;

    //default constructor method
    public HeadPhone(){
        this.manufacturer = "Bose";
        this.headPhoneColor = Color.black;
        this.volume = MEDIUM;
        this.pluggedIn = false;       
    } // end default constructor
    // getter method
    public String getManufacturer(){
        return manufacturer;
    }
    // getter method
    public Color getColor(){
        return headPhoneColor;
    }
    // getter method
    public int getVolume(){
        return volume;
    }
    // getter method
    public boolean getStatus(){
        return pluggedIn;
    }   

    public int changeVolume(int change){
        volume = change;
        return volume;
    }
    // setter method
    public void setNewHeadphone(){
        manufacturer = "JVC";
        headPhoneColor = Color.blue;
        pluggedIn = true;
        volume = HIGH;
    }

  //  @Override
  //  public String toString(){
  //      return "Head Phone 1 has the folllowing parameters: " + "\n" + 
  //              "Manufacturer: " + this.manufacturer + "\n" + "Color: Black" + 
  //              "\n" + "Volume is set to: " + this.volume + "\n" + 
  //              "Currently: disconnected" + "\n" + "Please plug the Head Phone"
  //              + " into a device"; 
  //  }

}
```

**My Output:**
Manufacturer: Bose
Color: java.awt.Color[r=0, g=0, b=0]
Currently: false
Volume: 2
Please plug the Head Phones into a device.

Manufacturer: JVC
Color: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
Currently: true
Volume: 3
Currently playing classical music.

**Required output:**
Manufacturer: Bose
Color: Black
Currently: disconnected
Volume is set to: MEDIUM
Please plug the Head Phones into a device.

Head Phone 2 has the following parameters:
Manufacturer: JVC
Color: Blue
Currently: connected
Volume is set to: LOW
Currently playing classical music playlist

Comment: Are you still having problems progressing forward?

Comment: I am. I still can't figure out how to get the string values and use the toString() method. so

Comment: what does it print now?

Comment: Manufacturer: Bose   Color: java.awt.Color[r=0, g=0, b=0]   Currently: disconnected   Volume: 2   Please plug the Head Phones into a device.  I had to use an if loop to print the word "disconnected" instead of false but I don't think that's what the instructions meant

Comment: Which property is still not printing as you expect them to? Besides **color**

Answer (score 5):

You can override the `toString()` methods of the objects you want to print. However some objects already have their `toString()` methods implemented for you with a human-readable format. i.e. the `Color` class.

```
    ...
    System.out.println("Color: " + headPhone.getColor().toString());
    ...
```

On the other hand, you have the freedom to specify what format the object shall be displayed as a `String` by overriding. (Unless there are class restrictions on what can/cannot be modified, i.e. the `final` keyword.)

Answer (score 1):

If overriding the `toString()` methods end up being not possible for your project, you can always just explicitly format the display string conditionally using their primitive values. i.e.

```
System.out.println("Currently: " + (headPhone.getStatus() ? "connected" : "disconnected"));
...
```

Be aware of the issue that you will need to do this each time you want to print out the `status` in other parts of the code. overriding the `toString()` does it everywhere, uniformly.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this code. It may help.

```
public class TestHeadPhones {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HeadPhones h1 = new HeadPhones();
    h1.setVolume(2);
    h1.setHeadPhoneColor("CYAN");
    h1.setManufacturer("Bass");
    h1.setPluggedIn(true);
    HeadPhones h2 = new HeadPhones();
    h2.setVolume(1);
    h2.setHeadPhoneColor("blue");
    h2.setManufacturer("Bass");
    h2.setPluggedIn(true);
    HeadPhones h3 = new HeadPhones();
    h3.setVolume(HeadPhones.HIGH);
    h3.setHeadPhoneColor("DARK GRAY");
    h3.setManufacturer("Bass");
    h3.setPluggedIn(true);

    // Print description of all headphones
    System.out.println("Description of Headphone 1");
    System.out.println(h1.toString() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Description of Headphone 2");

    System.out.println(h2.toString() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Description of Headphone 3");

    System.out.println(h3.toString() + "\n");


    //change volume of headphone 1
    h1.changeVolume(3);
    System.out.println("Description of Headphone 1");
    System.out.println(h1.toString() + "\n");

}

}
```

Here is the HeadPhones class

```
public class HeadPhones {
public static final int LOW = 1;
public static final int MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int HIGH = 3;
private int volume = MEDIUM;
private boolean pluggedIn = false;
private String manufacturer;
private String headPhoneColor;

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public HeadPhones() { 

}

/***
 * Change the voulme
 * @param value
 */
public void changeVolume(int value) {
    setVolume(value);
}

/**
 * Return Description of Object
 */
public String toString() {
    return "Volume: " + getVolume() + "\n" + "Plugin is set: "
            + isPluggedIn() + "\n" + "Color of HeadePhone: "
            + getHeadPhoneColor() + "\n" + "Manufacturer: "
            + getManufacturer();
}

/**
 * Set volume
 * @param volume
 */
public void setVolume(int volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

/***
 * Get Volume
 * @return volume
 */
public int getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

/**
 * Set plugin
 * @param pluggedIn
 */
public void setPluggedIn(boolean pluggedIn) {
    this.pluggedIn = pluggedIn;
}

/***
 * Get Plugin is true or false
 * @return pluggedIn
 */
public boolean isPluggedIn() {
    return pluggedIn;
}

/***
 * Set Manufacture
 * @param manufacturer
 */
public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

/***
 * Get Manufacture
 * @return manufacturer
 */
public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

/***
 * Set the Color
 * @param headPhoneColor
 */
public void setHeadPhoneColor(String headPhoneColor) {
    this.headPhoneColor = headPhoneColor;
}

/**
 * This method will return the color
 * @return headPhoneColor
 */
public String getHeadPhoneColor() {
    return headPhoneColor;
}

}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: the toString() method in the TestHeadPhones class works

Comment: For example: `System.out.println("Description of Headphone 1");
    System.out.println(h1.toString() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Description of Headphone 2");`

Comment: The answer is a giant code dump with no explanation.

Comment: Maybe I should have put out `System.out.println(h1.toString() + "\n");` only